# Can I choose multiple lines in intellij only used keyboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

I knew that I can implement this feature using Shift + Alt + Mouse click, but because I do not use mouse frequently, is there any way that I can choose multiple lines only use keyboard?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html: you can press Ctrl (for Windows or UNIX) / Alt (for macOS) twice, and then without releasing it, press the up or down arrow keys. If you want to delete all added cursors, press Escape.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> ?

Comment: I mean separate lines, like Shift + Alt + MouseLeft

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that from the question. I think the problem is to clone your caret to the right location somewhere else in the text. There is such thing as Alt + J but this is quite specific.